# Mix colors in JavaScript canvas using canvas functions

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a HTML `<canvas>` with an object and I'm trying to animate its color.

For example, I might want to animate from `rgb(255, 240, 100)` to `rgb(255, 255, 255)`.  While it is possible to calculate the intermediate color by some string processing and concatenation, I am trying to avoid that as assigning a ad-hoc constructed string as a `fillStyle` seems to be significantly slower than having the `fillStyle` set to a specific value (at least, in Chrome).

Is there any way, through use things like `globalCompositionOperation` or something else, to avoid concatenating my color strings?

Comment: Building color values with string concatenation is not really that slow. How exactly are you doing it?

Comment: Something like `return "rgb("+Math.round(color_arr[0]).toString()+","+Math.round(color_arr[1]).toString()+","+Math.round(color_arr[2]).toString()+")";`.  It's actually good enough for my use, but I'm wondering if I can do better.

Comment: Well for one thing you don't need to call `.toString()`. It would be much easier to tell if you were to post the code **in the question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example that paints a square and fades its fill color.
It interpolates between 2 color values and I think the result is pretty smooth.
Maybe something else degrades the performance of you animation.

```js
function getColorStr(r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2, pct) {
  var rn = Math.round((1-pct) * r1 + pct * r2),
      gn = Math.round((1-pct) * g1 + pct * g2),
      bn = Math.round((1-pct) * b1 + pct * b2);
  return 'rgb('+rn+','+gn+','+bn+')'
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cW = canvas.width,
    cH = canvas.height;

var color1 = [255, 240, 100],
    color2 = [255, 255, 255];
var cycleLength = 2;
var cyclePct = 0;
var lastTs = Date.now();

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cW, cH);

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  
function draw() {
  var now = Date.now();
  var dt = (now - lastTs)/1000; //seconds
  cyclePct += dt/cycleLength;
  if (cyclePct > 1) cyclePct = 0;
  lastTs = now;
  
  var color = getColorStr(color1[0], color1[1], color1[2], color2[0], color2[1], color2[2], cyclePct);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="200"/>
```